# Is it possible to handle fields containing line breaks in awk?

Tags: text, csv, awk, newline, gawk

Suppose I have a text file with records of the following form, where the `FS` is generally speaking a comma, and the `RS` is generally speaking a newline.

However, the exception to this rule is that if a field is in quotes, it should treat the line breaks and commas as part of the field.

```
"This field contains
line breaks and is
quoted but it 
should be treated as a 
single field",1,2,3,"another field"
```

**How can I use awk to parse such a file correctly, where I can still access `$1,$2...`, as I usually would, but with the above interpretation of fields?**

I have already looked at [this wiki page](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/snipplets/awkcsv), but the solution presented there does not solve the problem of line breaks.

Comment: It might be possible, but it would be highly fragile. Awk, like most unix tools, is designed to process data (not formatting), one line at a time. breaking that "contract" with your tool set leads to a whole world of pain. As you need to reference $1, etc, I'm really at a loss to offer any kind of hack. I'll be happy to be proved wrong ;-) A pre and post filter that flattens the record using something like &#*^@ as the replacement for `\n` is the only thing that comes to mind. Good luck.

Comment: This is not as trivial as it might seem...is awk the only option?

Comment: No, I could write it in Python, but it seems like for this problem it is really a delimiter problem for awk, rather than some more fundamental limitation, so I wanted to try to make it work in awk.

Comment: Just guessing: was your problem solved? I posted an answer yesterday with a new approach.

Comment: @fedorqui, I think I originally ended up using Python or some other full language. However, I will try your solution and accept if it works.

Answer (score 0):

A possible, although not  perfect, solution is this: `awk 'BEGIN{RS="\""}{...}'`. By doing this you reset the record separator to be `"`, while the field separator remains a space. The problem is that this will add two empty record to your file, because also the first and last `"` will be matched as delimiting some records.

Example:

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="\""}  {print $0,"END OF RECORD",$1,"-",$2}'
```

will produce this result when applied to your data

```
 END OF RECORD  - 
This field contains
line breaks and is
quoted but it 
should be treated as a 
single field END OF RECORD This - field
,1,2,3, END OF RECORD ,1,2,3, - 
another field END OF RECORD another - field

END OF RECORD  -
```

You can skip the first one by adding the condtion `NR>1` . The last one is a bit more tricky though, because you do not know how many records are there in your file. You can save the values you want to print in an array and print them using a `for` cycle in the `END` statement, skipping the first and last record in your file.

Answer (score 0):

To get awk to parse the file correctly, you can use a program I wrote called csvquote that temporarily replaces the commas and newlines that appear inside quoted fields with nonprinting characters that won't confuse awk. This program santizes the data into a format where awk can rely on a comma always representing a field separator, and a newline always representing a record separator.

To use it, you wrap your pipeline involving cut/awk/... like this:

```
csvquote /tmp/foo.csv | tail +2 | awk -F, '{print $3 $2}' | csvquote -u
```

You can find the code here: https://github.com/dbro/csvquote

The one caveat is that if you want to search for commas and newlines inside fields, this makes that task more complicated because you would need to search for the nonprinting characters instead. If you are looking for a way to do this more easily, you should look into the csvfix tools.

Another option is to use awk's FPAT, but that won't work if the fields contain escaped quotation marks. See http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Splitting-By-Content.html

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use double new line as record separator. If you also set comma as the field separator, then this allows you to handle each block of text as a field:

```
awk -v RS="\n\n" -v FS="," '...' file
```

For your given file, let's show the file number together with the file itself:

```
$ awk -v RS="\n\n" -v FS="," '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) print i, $i}' file
1 "This field contains
line breaks and is
quoted but it 
should be treated as a 
single field"
2 1
3 2
4 3
5 "another field"
```

Comment: This does not seem to work with multiple records because you require double newline separation, and the original question requires single newline separators.

Comment: True, it would just work if records are separated with double new line. I will try to figure out a better solution, let's see if I manage to :)

Answer (score 0):

## Use -k or --csv

Both Brian Kernighan's `awk` and GNU `gawk` now support CSV files directly.

Here is what the GNU gawk manual says:

> For decades, anyone wishing to work with CSV files and awk had to “roll their own” solution. (For an example, see Defining Fields by Content). In 2023, Brian Kernighan decided to add CSV support to his version of awk. In order to keep up, gawk too provides the same support as his version. To use CSV data, invoke gawk with either of the -k or --csv options.

### Example

```bash
echo '"This field contains
line breaks and is
quoted but it 
should be treated as a 
single field",1,2,3,"another field"' | 
  awk --csv '
  {
    print NR, $1
  }
  '
```

### Caveats

- You'll need gawk ≥ v5.3 or BWK's awk from 2023.
- CSV is interpreted strictly according to [RFC 4180](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4180), which only encapsulates the most common practices, not variants like using semicolons as delimiters.