# How to clean bad data from huge csv file

Tags: sql, linux, bigdata

So I have huge csv file (assume 5 GB) and I want to insert the data to the table but it return error that the length of the data is not the same

I found that some data has more columns than I want 
For example the correct data I have has 8 columns but some data has 9 (it can be human/system error)

I want to take only 8 columns data, but because the data is so huge, I can not do it manually or using parsing in python

Any recommendation of a way to do it?

I am using linux, so any linux command also welcome

In sql I am using COPY ... FROM ... CSV HEADER; command to import the csv into table

Comment: You should be able to handle this with the load operation for the database you are using.  But you haven't even specified the database, so you'll end up copying the file.

Comment: I am sorry that I forget to put my the database information, I use postgresql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `awk` for this purpose. Assuming you field delimiter is comma (`,`) this code can do the work:

```
awk -F\, 'NF==8 {print}' input_file >output_file
```

Comment: CSV is not line structured. It is possible, that a CSV rows covers more than 1 line. And it is possible, that a field contains a comma. For both cases, the script above is broken and returns a wrong result.

Comment: @Wiimm, CSV by definition is row oriented. And if field delimiter is used in the field this should be mentioned explicitly by OP. And you can check OP comment.

Comment: A CSV row can cover 2 or more physical lines (in sense of awk). A field can contain a newline and a comma (both are included in quotes). And both is ignored by your solution.

Comment: ahh I understand what @Wiimm means, so basically if the data contains newlines, we need to be careful. fortunately my data not contain newline character but it is good to know that such possibility exist

Comment: I found similar question about awk and newline in csv. but because I still new in awk so I will put the link here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16094067/is-it-possible-to-handle-fields-containing-line-breaks-in-awk

Answer (score 1):

A fast and dirty php solution as single command line:

```
php -r '$f=fopen("a.csv","rb"); $g=fopen("b.csv","wb"); while ( $r=fgetcsv($f) ) { $r = array_slice($r,0,8); fputcsv($g,$r); }'
```

It reads file `a.csv` and writes `b.csv`.

Comment: This provides what benefit?